# Can the recaptcha character set be set?

Tags: c#-4.0, recaptcha, mvcrecaptcha

I was wondering if there is a setting that can override the set of characters that will be shown on the captcha screen? I'm using the captcha plugin from Microsoft.Web.Helpers.

Any other mvc captcha library that anyone can recommend? I'm currently using CaptchaMVC but when refresh is click all the values entered on the form are reset.

Thanks,
czetsuya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used: http://www.google.com/recaptcha. I think it's one of the captcha libraries available on different programming language and is widely use.